# PHP & file_get_contents - check if file exists

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, url

So in .htaccess:

```
# Always have the brand new version of jQuery
<FilesMatch "^(jquery-2\.1\.1)\.js$">
SetHandler php5-script
</FilesMatch>
```

And in jquery-2.1.1.js:

```
<?php
$jquery = file_get_contents('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js');
echo $jquery;
?>
```

I have 2 questions:
Is this a good practise? I'm tired of looking for a new jQuery version at the jQuery wesite so I want to include it from there and so it'll update automatically. But if they happen to remove this file I want PHP to look for it on this link: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js
I think `if()` statements should be used here, any opinions?

Comment: I'd be careful about auto-updating your version of jQuery (or anything, for that matter) as it may break some of your scripts and/or plugins.

Comment: Break them? I'd have agreed with this statement if new browsers hadn't been updated every time a new feature comes out and I've dropped support for the ancient IE versions anyway, so I don't think it's a great matter...

Comment: You lost me. What do browsers have to do with this?

Comment: Well wehn something new is added to a programming language the programs that read it also update to maintain compability.

Comment: That's not true. There are *plenty* of jQuery plugins that never get updated and will break as soon as you update to a newer version. Same goes for Wordpress plugins, ett. Also, if a script IS updated it's certainly not at the exact same time your jQuery installation is updated. Even if it's only 10 hours later, you site is broken for 10 hours.

Comment: It sure is, but after each edit I check it myself for a couple of times and if it is really broken I revert to an older version. I always have a backup for changes that I'm not sure I can revert myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not good practice for a few reasons the most important of which is you can never be sure that the newest version of jquery will work with your code. Updates to core libraries should be deliberate and well tested, not automated.

Other reasons not to do it:

1) Unnecessary overhead in the application

2) static assets should be served from a CDN - (google hosted jquery works great for this)
https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

I'm sure there are more but these should be enough.

Comment: Yeah, sure I could link to it from another server but I kndda like to have control over the files, have them on my own server...

Comment: If you want to keep them on your own server (which by the way is not optimal since your servers are in one location and your users are spread out over the world) then you still wouldn't want to auto update your libraries due to legacy code breakage.

Comment: Alright then, looks like I'll continue looking for new versions every time. Thanks anyways... Gonna accept this answer.